# Scale and translate a custom view

Tags: java, android, zooming, scaling, translate

I need to be able to pinch zoom on my view and i'd like the pivot point to be the middle of my fingers. I also need the view to be two-finger scrollable. My problem is that if I haven't scrolled the view yet, it correctly zooms on the center of my fingers. But if I zoom after having translated the view, it doesn't. It also seems to randomly teleport when I zoom and then zoom again.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(dx, dy);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,milieudoigtsX,milieudoigtsY);
    ... //my draw instructions
    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {



    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        PlotView.this.milieudoigtsX = (PlotView.this.mPrimStartTouchEventX+PlotView.this.mSecStartTouchEventX)/2;
        PlotView.this.milieudoigtsY = (PlotView.this.mPrimStartTouchEventY+PlotView.this.mSecStartTouchEventY)/2;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        PlotView.this.mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        PlotView.this.mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        PlotView.this.dy -= distanceY;
        PlotView.this.dx -= distanceX;
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }


}
```

I must precise that I detect a pinching or a scroll action, so my gesture listener and my scale listener are never called at the same time.

Thanks for your help

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/ARUXXTFC - if you want custom drawing then call `Canvs#concat` inside `onDraw` method

Comment: Okay, should I redefine a view class though ? I also need to be able to select lines on my drawing and highlight them to show when they're selected.

Comment: simply use `MatrixGestureDetector` or any other that is `Matrix` based

Comment: It tells me that lambda expressions and method references aren't supported at language level 1.7. Sorry I'm really not familiar with all this

Comment: so use old style `imageView.setOnTouchListener(listener)` where `listener = new OnTouchListener(...` etc - i used 1.8 features to make it more compact

Comment: Done it, it displays my drawing but I can't zoom or move it. Here is the class i've written https://pastebin.com/raw/HgrkZbsZ
I just copied the MatrixGestureDetector as you told me

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/Km9bEzw8

Comment: does it zoom and move now?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I'm starting to get the hang of it but I still can't figure out how to apply this to a drawing canvas. I understood how it worked with the staticLayout, but I can't find how to do something similar to my shapes. Indeed if I just put the drawing instructions in onDraw, it redraws with the base coordinates every time so it's neither scrollable nor zoomable. Thanks for your help https://pastebin.com/raw/HHvaejTE

Comment: did you see where i am calling `canvas.concat()` method? do the same

Comment: Well yeah I see, but I did the same didn't I ? Still it doesn't work

Comment: no, you did not - whats the point of changing the canvas after drawing your lines?

Comment: Ooooh okay thanks ! I had badly understood how it worked !

Comment: Just another quick question if you don't mind :D Is there a possibility in removing the rotation (it is not needed in what I'm doing) and forcing a two finger scroll (I'll do a drag and drop with one finger) ? I thought about modifying the gesture detector, but I need to fully understand how it works. Also if I want to have my touch coordinates relatively to the canvas should I use homogeneous coordinates with the matrix that I've got ?

Comment: sure: use some other detector like https://pastebin.com/raw/8dmUq3gF

Comment: Well thanks a lot I've managed to do everything I wanted :D